# pylirc returns none all the time

Tags: raspbian, python

I'm trying to write simple IR receiver code using pylirc in python but the function `Pylirc.nextcode(1)` always returns `None`! I ran a test and everything is good, the terminal and the shell in python can detect the pressed button.

What can I do?

```
import pylirc, time

blocking = 0;

#
if(pylirc.init("pylirc", "./conf", blocking)):

   code = {"config" : ""}
   while(code["config"] != "quit"):

      # Very intuitive indeed
      if(not blocking):
         print "."

         # Delay...
         time.sleep(1)

      # Read next code
      s = pylirc.nextcode(1)

      # Loop as long as there are more on the queue
      # (dont want to wait a second if the user pressed many buttons...)
      while(s):

         # Print all the configs...
         for (code) in s:

            print "Command: %s, Repeat: %d" % (code["config"], code["repeat"])

            if(code["config"] == "blocking"):
               blocking = 1
               pylirc.blocking(1)

            elif(code["config"] == "nonblocking"):
               blocking = 0
               pylirc.blocking(0)

         # Read next code?
         if(not blocking):
            s = pylirc.nextcode(1)
         else:
            s = []

   # Clean up lirc
   pylirc.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run **pylirc.nextcode()** it pulls the next code, and only the next code, from the **Pylirc** queue. ie Even if you have five codes in queue `s = pylirc.nextcode()` gives you `s = [code]`. No matter how many codes are entered it only pulls one an assigns it to the first position in your list.

To get the next code from the queue you'll have to run **pylirc.nextcode()** each time you want the next code in queue, which will overwrite the last code in the first position.

Answer (score -2):

This may not be relevant.
I use lirc from https://github.com/tompreston/python-lirc

but I do lirc.nextcode() # without any arguments

and I get values all the time